# Accessing attributes of all elements in list simultaneously

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a list `list_of_locations` in Python where the elements are Pandas dataframes, let's call them `d` (question is valid for other lists of other classes as well).
If I want to extract an attribute, say `Latitude`, of the first DataFrame, I can - as expected - do `list_of_locations[0].Latitude`.

Now comes the question: I'd like to extract the values of `Latitude` for all elements in that list simultaneously, i.e. without looping over the list. How do I do that?
`list_of_locations[:].Latitude` does not work, because `type(list_of_locations[:])`  returns `list`.
Is there a simple way to access all the list elements at once, or do I have to resort to the for-loop? By the way: Why does `list_of_locations[0]` return the element and not a list of length 1?

EDIT: The desired behaviour can be reached by using a for-loop and list comprehension (as an alternative to the marked answer):

```
latitudes=[list_of_locations[i].Latitude for i in range(0,len(list_of_locations))]
```

Comment: _without looping over the list._ Why? _By the way: Why does list_of_locations[0] return the element and not a list of length 1?_ That's a somewhat ambiguous question: Were you expecting it to return a list with a single element, or are you asking for the rationale behind the current behaviour?

Comment: You cannot do that. You must loop, one way or another, either explicitely using a `for` loop, or using some sort of comprehension construct, which is also a loop underneath the hood, or something like `map` which is again, looping. Or even, recursion, but again, that is just another way to loop.

Comment: "By the way: Why does `list_of_locations[0]` return the element and not a list of length 1?" Because that is what a list is, a heterogenous sequence of objects that you access by `int` index. i.e. `list_of_locations[0]` is the *first* object in the list, `list_of_locations[1]` is the *second* object in the list, why did you expect it to return a list of length 1? What use would that be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, you should loop over the list `list_of_locations` to retrieve data from its elements. Thankfully, there are many compact ways of looping over iterables in Python. A one-liner that should solve your main question would be `list(map(lambda d: d.Latitude, list_of_locations))`. For more reference of the function map, [here is its official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map).

About your last question, this is a design decision made by Python, probably inspired by how arrays work in C. Personally, I do not expect to receive a list when indexing a list of depth 1, but this is probably due to my background in C and Python when learning how to code.